# search for suitable algorithms for the space minimization problem

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search, knapsack-problem

advise me a solution idea and algorithms can help me solve this problem:
there is a field on which there is a main element (red color) and additional elements (other colors), which must be connected by at least one cell of the connecting element (gray color) to the main element. goal: minimize space usage and additionally adapt to the given field framework
[image]

most likely, the connection will need to be searched through variations of the BFS, packing most likely needs to be solved as a variation of the knapsack problems, but I did not find a suitable algorithm and I do not have a general idea of the global solution

Comment: Is rotation not allowed?

Comment: @MrSmith42 no, rotations are not allowed